# itextsharp: how do i set the background color of the document?

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext

in vb.net please if possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a `Rectangle` object and set its `BackgroundColor` property.  Use your `Rectangle` to initialize your `Document`.

[This tutorial](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/tutorial/ch01.html) on the iTextSharp site on SourceForge describes this (see the PageSize section).

The same site has a [code sample](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/examples/Chap0102.cs) that demonstrates what you need to do.  (see 'step 1').  The sample is in C# and I know you want it in VB.NET so I ran it through the [C# to VB.NET converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) on the developerfusion site.  I can't test compile the results from the machine I'm not now, but the code looks reasonable:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO

Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf

Public Class Chap0102

    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("Chapter 1 example 2: PageSize")

        ' step 1: creation of a document-object
        Dim pageSize As New Rectangle(144, 720)
        pageSize.BackgroundColor = New Color(&Hff, &Hff, &Hde)
        Dim document As New Document(pageSize)

        Try

            ' step 2:
            ' we create a writer that listens to the document
            ' and directs a PDF-stream to a file

            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, New FileStream("Chap0102.pdf", FileMode.Create))

            ' step 3: we open the document
            document.Open()

            ' step 4: we Add some paragraphs to the document
            For i As Integer = 0 To 4
                document.Add(New Paragraph("Hello World"))

            Next
        Catch de As DocumentException
            Console.[Error].WriteLine(de.Message)
        Catch ioe As IOException
            Console.[Error].WriteLine(ioe.Message)
        End Try

        ' step 5: we close the document
        document.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

`color` does not exist in namespace and the error is in your code:

```
pageSize.BackgroundColor = New **Color**(&Hff, &Hff, &Hde)
```